# Confidence interval for population variance and chi-square distribution

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, variance, chi-squared-distribution

At present, i am reading the e-book by Robert L. Mcdonald(Professor of Finance,Northwestern University's Kellogg school of Management) named $"Derivatives Markets" 3rd Edition.$ In that book,  I didn't understand his computation of confidence interval for variance. He wrote as follows:

The variability of the variance estimate is described by the chi-squared distribution. (The chi-squared distribution is the distribution of sums of squared independent standard normal variables; hence, it describes
the distribution of the estimated variance when observations are independent.) Suppose we wish to test the null hypothesis that our variance estimate $s^2=\sigma_0^2$ and that we have $n$ observations. The variable $\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma_0^2}$  has the chi-squared distribution with n − 1 degrees of freedom. If we wish to perform a two-tailed test when we have six observations, the critical values for 0.975 and 0.025 confidence are 0.831 and 12.832. If our null hypothesis is that  $\sigma_0^2=0.09$, then the 95% confidence interval is $0.01496-0.23097.$

Now my question is how did the author compute this confidence interval? My computation shows it should be $0.035065-0.54156.$

If you need more information about the information or example cited by the author, I am ready to provide.

Comment: Is there something missing here about the value of $s^2$? You would usually be computing a ci for the observed value not the hypothesised population value.

Comment: @mdewey,In the Author's example,  there were six observations of stock prices log returns for 7 weeks whose standard deviation $s$ is 0.2755. So variance $s^2=0.07590025$

Comment: Well that is weird. That still does not give the range he quotes. Either you and I are both making the same mistake or he is wrong and I do not know how we are going to find out unless someone else can help us.

Comment: @mdewey Hypotheses always refer to parameters, not to data, so there appears to be nothing the matter with the statement of the question.  Dhamnekar: It's straightforward to apply the information you give to determine the answer is indeed $$(0.831,12.832)\times \frac{\sigma_0^2}{n-1}=(0.831,12.832) \times \frac{0.09}{6-1} = (0.014958, 0.230976).$$ This shows your computation is wrong, but since you don't describe your computation, there's little one can say.

Comment: @whuber, Thanks for pointing out where i was wrong. Your's and Author's computations for confidence intervals for $\sigma^2$ are correct.